# Password Protect Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, passwords, password-protection

so I have created a small script here for my google sheets. Since google sheets doesn't allow you to use password protection on individual sheets, I was wondering if there was a way to protect my script with a password so that only certain people can use it. Here is my code.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Record', 'Record')
      .addItem('Cancelation', 'Cancel')
      .addToUi();
}

function Record() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Nightly Stats'),
    row = sheet.getLastRow()
    range = sheet.getRange("A3:G3");
  sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that you can provide.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could understand correctly your question, can I ask you about the difference with sharing the Spreadsheet with the specific users? In that case, users are required to login to Google.

Comment: Do you have many users of the same spreadsheet?  Or each user has their own spreadsheet?

Comment: There are many users that can access the spreadsheet. What I found is that if I protect individual worksheets then the script cannot edit them at all, so I want to use a password so that only certain people can use the script if that makes any sense. My thought was that I could maybe use a prompt to do this... Like if the response from a prompt == some text, then they can continue with the script....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I actually figured out how to do a password system via prompting. Here was what I did in case anyone needs this in the future.

```
function Cancel() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // first prompt
  var presult = ui.prompt(
    "Please Enter the Password to Use this Feature.",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var password = "Test";
  var pbutton = presult.getSelectedButton();
  var ptext = presult.getResponseText();

  // User clicked "OK" on first prompt
  if (pbutton == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    ui.alert('The Process Was Ended.');
    } else if (pbutton == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
      ui.alert('The Process Was Ended.');
    } else if (ptext != password) {
      Password();   
    } else {
      "Insert whatever action you would want them to do after the password works here"
    }
  }

function Password() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("The Password is Incorrect. Retry?",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    ui.alert("The Process Was Ended.");
  } else if (response == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    ui.alert("The Process Was ended.");
  } else {
    Cancel();
  }
}
```

I only gave a piece of the code so sorry if it looks a little weird. I just didn't want to give the whole code and make you search for everything. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Wouldn't this just store the password as plain text in the sheet, which would be accessible to whomever was using the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

It is a trick but it's useful to free account user!
Use `onOpen()` function and little code below.

```
var inputPassword;
function checkPassword(){  
  
  var refAddress = 'https://script.google.com/d/' + ScriptApp.getScriptId() + '/edit';
  var curAddress = refAddress;
  Logger.log(curAddress);  
  
  var referPassword = 1234;

  if( refAddress == curAddress){
      while(referPassword != inputPassword){
      inputPassword = Browser.inputBox('[Password Check]', '[Input Password!]', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to [my blog](https://blog.naver.com/dsayhong/222221373617) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to protect the script itself?
Host the script in a different location and use a library:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries